# Is it possible to define a custom rest template?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to define a common bean to be used for all my application so to add inside a logger and other logic. My idea would be:

```
public class MyRestTemplate extends RestTemplate{
```

Then:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

   @Bean
   public MyRestTemplate myRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder){ 
       return (MyRestTemplate) builder.build(); //throws classcast exception!
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way? I want to be sure that people will have to use my customized class.

Comment: I think [Configure a RestTemplate with RestTemplateBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder) article covers possible options. I don't see other ways how to force the usage of your custom `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

`builder.build()` returns a `RestTemplate`, not a `MyRestTemplate`.

If you change your code as shown below you would create a bean named `myRestTemplate`. Spring use the name of the method as bean name if you don't override it in the `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

   @Bean
   public RestTemplate myRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder){ 
       return builder.build(); //throws classcast exception!
   }
}
```

Please also see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/boot-features-restclient.html

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. @Phate wanted to have a custom instance of `RestTemplate` and not the default one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some customizations in your restTemplate you could define a class that implements RestTemplateCustomizer and add a custom interceptor to it.

```
public class CustomRestTemplateCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Then you have to define that custom interceptor for all the requests going out of this restTemplate with

```
public class CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        // This is where you can do a lot of thing with this request like logging
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

And finally, just define a bean for the custom restTemplate you have written

```
@Bean
public CustomRestTemplateCustomizer customRestTemplateCustomizer() {
    return new CustomRestTemplateCustomizer();
}
```

Comment: But this way I'll only customize a customizer, the develop will have to create a rest template using this customization